fetch data from strapi 4 with populate and filter
i am using strapi 4. I want to fetch data with ** populate parent** of table **features ** is null.
it will works when i use API:
/projects?populate[features][populate]=parent

but when i use this API to get data with parent of features is null,
/projects?populate[features][populate]=parent&filters[features][parent][$null]=true
it will be log an
error: 
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    }
}

enter image description here
So what i need change in my API to do this?
